# Strongly inaccessible cardinals and certain kinds of universes

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Write $\mathrm{tc}(*)$ for [transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set#Transitive_closure).

For all cardinals $\kappa$, let $H(\kappa)$ denote the collection of all sets $X$ such that

1. $|X|<\kappa$, and
2. For all $x \in \mathrm{tc}(X)$, it holds that $|x| < \kappa$.

Consider the class $K$ of all cardinals $\kappa$ such that $H(\kappa)$ is closed under powersets and unions. i.e. the class of all $\kappa$ such that

1. For all $X \in H(\kappa)$ it holds that $\mathcal{P}(X) \in H(\kappa)$
2. For all $X \in H(\kappa)$ it holds that $\bigcup X \in H(\kappa)$.

Is $K$ precisely the class of all [strongly inaccessible cardinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal)? (include $0$ and $\omega$ in the definition of strongly inaccessible cardinals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fact**: $H(\kappa)$ is closed under unions iff $\kappa$ is regular.
**Proof**: If $\kappa$ is not regular then any cofinal sequence of ordinals in $\kappa$ witnessing its singularity also witnesses that $H(\kappa)$ is not closed under unions.  Conversely, suppose $\kappa$ is regular, and let $X \in H(\kappa)$.  Since $\mathrm{tc}\left(\bigcup X\right) \subseteq \mathrm{tc}(X)$, it'll suffice to show that $\left|\bigcup X\right| < \kappa$.  But this follows from the fact that $\kappa$ is regular, and that $\bigcup X$ is a union of $< \kappa$ many elements each of size $< \kappa$.

**Fact**: $H(\kappa)$ is closed under power sets iff $\kappa$ is strong limit.
**Proof**: If $H(\kappa)$ is closed under power sets, then $\kappa$ is clearly strong limit.  Conversely, suppose $H(\kappa)$ were not closed under power sets, and suppose $X \in H(\kappa)$ witnesses this.  Since every element of the transitive closure of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is either a subset of $X$ or an element of $\mathrm{tc}(X)$, the only way we can have $\mathcal{P}(X) \notin H(\kappa)$ is if $|\mathcal{P}(X)| \geq \kappa$.  But then we have $|X| < \kappa$; $|\mathcal{P}(X)| = 2^{|X|} \geq \kappa$.  And so $\kappa$ is not strong limit.

Strictly speaking, a cardinal must be uncountable to be considered inaccessible, so the two properties you listed aren't equivalent to inaccessibility.  But your two properties, *together with uncountability*, are equivalent to inaccessibility.

EDIT: Just noticed you say you want to consider $0$ and $\omega$ to be strongly inaccessible.  *If* you do this, then yes, your two conditions are equivalent to strong inaccessibility.  But *why* would you do this?

Comment: Where does uncountability come into it?

Comment: It's part of the definition of inaccessible.  Note that $\omega$ is a strong limit regular cardinal.  $2^n$ is finite if $n$ is finite, and adding finitely many finite numbers together is finite.

Comment: I edited the question by redefining "strongly inaccessible cardinal". Does this remove the need for uncountability? It seems not to feature in either proof given above.

Comment: "Inaccessible" is synonymous with "strongly inaccessible".  Uncountability isn't needed in the proofs, but it's part of the definition of inaccessibility, so it's necessary in that sense.  I can see that putting the assumption about uncountability at the top of the post might have been confusing, so I've removed it, and added some clarification to the summary statement.

Comment: Cool. Out of curiosity, is $0$ also a strong limit regular cardinal?

Comment: "If you do this, then yes, your two conditions are equivalent to strong inaccessibility. But why would you do this?" Dunno. Just trying to see the connections between things.

Comment: Fair enough :).

Comment: Oh. I've just noticed that by definition, $0$ is not a limit cardinal. So don't both answering that.

Comment: @user18921: We use uncountability because we want $H(\kappa)$ to be a model of ZFC and if $\kappa=0$ then $H(\kappa)=\varnothing$; and if $\kappa=\omega$ then $H(\kappa)$ fails to satisfy the axiom of infinity. But otherwise $\omega$ is an inaccessible cardinal.